# How to avoid bool property to automaticly be added to element of a list (c#)?

Tags: c#

I have the following c# code:

```
   public class Res1
   {
        public string Name1   { get; set; }
        public string Name2   { get; set; }
        public bool   NameDef { get; set; }
   }
   ...
   ...
   List<Res1> list1 = new List<Res1> { };
   list1.Add(new Res1 { Name1 = "testName" });
```

The result of list1 will be:

```
[{"Name1":"testName","NameDef":false}]
```

But I only want the list entry to contain Name1, if NameDef not set, as for Name2 (string)

How do I avoid the bool property to automaticly be added to element of the list?

Comment: Try change type of NameDef to `bool?` .

Comment: `bool` type always have a value. You must use `Nullable<bool>` type

Comment: Thanks everybody, for quick and correct answers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't achieve this with a `bool` datatype. It has ever a value (default is false). With a `bool?` datatype (Nullable boolean) it should work.

```
public class Res1
{
     public string Name1   { get; set; }
     public string Name2   { get; set; }
     public bool?  NameDef { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your bool nullable by adding a `?` after it's type:

```
public class Res1
{
    public string Name1   { get; set; }
    public string Name2   { get; set; }
    public bool?   NameDef { get; set; } //mind the ?
}
...
...
List<Res1> list1 = new List<Res1> { };
list1.Add(new Res1 { Name1 = "testName" });
```

By default a `bool` always has to hold `true` or `false`, just like an `int` can only hold numbers - and not null. By adding a `?` after a non-nullable type you make it nullable. It's shorthand for `Nullable<bool>`. This way you effectively make them nullable.

MSDN has some further reading on [nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).